# How to configure Twilio on parse server?

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, twilio, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I am attempting to incorporate Twilio into my application that is running on my parse server deployed with Heroku and MongoLab. I am trying to  configure by using this code in my cloud/main.js file

```
var twilio = require("twilio");
twilio.initialize("87se46bovanw4v5aiwy4o57","ia8o57awyov57yn875vyboe");


Parse.Cloud.define("inviteWithTwilio", function(request, response) {
// Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS
twilio.sendSMS({
    From: "6543211234",
    To: 8065456703,
    Body: "Start using Parse and Twilio!"
  }, {
success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
  });
});
```

however, I get this response

```
    UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.} [NSDebugDescription: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.]
```

I have determined that the problem lies in the first two lines when trying to initialize Twilio. I figure this is because the `Twilio Cloud Module` isn't integrated into my parse server like it was with Parse Hosted cloud code, but I'm not sure. How can I fix this problem? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you installed the Twilio module into your application? `npm install twilio --save`. Also, the bug you are showing looks like it is from iOS, do you have any more information about where the error occurs in the server?

Comment: I get that error anytime something on the cloud side is incorrect. And I haven't installed the twilio module, however, my server is deployed through the web version of github with heroku (I didn't use the command line tool). Will installing this have any effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds like, from our conversation in the comments, like you have not installed the [Twilio npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio) just yet. On Parse, you didn't have to install the module as it was included by default. To use the Twilio module using Parse server you need it installed.

To install the module, open up your application in the terminal and type:

```
$ npm install twilio --save
```

The `--save` flag is important  as it saves the dependency to your `package.json` file. Check in the updated `package.json` and deploy your code again. Now, when deploying to Heroku the npm modules, including the Twilio module, will be installed.

Marin, who already answered as well, had a good point. I also recommend using `twilio.sendMessage`. It uses the newer and better featured [Messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) (rather than the deprecated SMS resource).

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Hooray! Hope the rest of your app goes well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is problem for Twilio version.

you should use twilio.sendMessage.

```
var twilio = require("twilio");
twilio.initialize("87se46bovanw4v5aiwy4o57","ia8o57awyov57yn875vyboe");


Parse.Cloud.define("inviteWithTwilio", function(request, response) {
// Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS
twilio.sendMessage({
    From: "6543211234",
    To: 8065456703,
    Body: "Start using Parse and Twilio!"
  }, {
success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
  });
});
```

Hope to help you.

Thanks

///////////////////////////////

Here is my code work fine.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendSMS", function(request, response) {

    console.log(request);
    var twilio = require("twilio")("ACCOUNT_SID","AUTH_TOKEN");

    twilio.sendMessage({

        to: request.params.number,
        from: request.params.from,
        body: request.params.message

    }, function(err, responseData) { 

        if (err) {
            response.error(err);
        } else { 
            response.success("SMS sent.");
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: I tried that and it's the same issue. I figured that wasn't the problem though because even if I don't call for the cloud function I get that response. However, if I comment off the top two lines, the server will run normally.

Comment: Is your code in the cloud/main.js on a parse-server?

Comment: /////////// Yes./////////////

Comment: Are the to and from values strings or integers? If they are strings what format are they in?

Comment: they are string type.